# how to remove app bar and change screen's orientation

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change screen areintation when I double tapped on my video stream and also make app bar and bottom bar remover. I have searched a lot, but now I can only change oreintation of screen, but can't remove appbar and bottom navigation, although nothing works.

```
//global variable for persist changing oreintation and removing app bar and bottom navigation

bool isPortrait = true;
```

//screen with live stream

```
   Stack(children: [
                    Positioned(
                      child: GestureDetector(
                        onDoubleTap: () {
                          isPortrait = !isPortrait;
                          if (isPortrait) {
                            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                              DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
                            ]);
                          } else {
                            SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
                              DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
                            ]);
                          }
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: SizedBox(
                          width: isPortrait
                              ? MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
                              : MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                          height: 420,
                          child: InAppWebView(
                              onReceivedServerTrustAuthRequest:
                                  (controller, challenge) async {
                                return ServerTrustAuthResponse(
                                    action: ServerTrustAuthResponseAction.PROCEED);
                              },
                              initialUrlRequest: URLRequest(
                                  url: Uri.parse(
                                      'https://1stream/home/stream'))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
```

screen where i persist app bar and bottom bar and screens:

```
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DefaultTabController(
        length: 4,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: isPortrait
              ? PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120),
                  child: AppBarService(),
                )
              : null,
          bottomNavigationBar: isPortrait ? menu() : null,
          body: TabBarView(
            //controller: tabControllerGlobally,
            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
            children: [
              MainPage(),
              HistoryPage(),
              DataBaseUser(),
//here my stream persist
              SettingsCameraUser()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your `isPortrait` variable shouldn't be global, it should be a part of the `StatefulWidget` for example in order for your widget(s) to rebuild when it changes.

Comment: @AnteBule but how can I get this variable in another screen? May be I can pass it in constructor?

Comment: Yes, or if it's too deep in the widget tree consider using one of the state management tools for that (such as `Provider`, `Bloc` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

First, make your widget `Stateful` and put the `isPortrait` variable in the `State` class:

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isPortrait = true;
...
```

Add to your screen the `callback` that will call when the user tap on your video. Below I make a simplified version of your screen

```
class SettingsCameraUser extends StatelessWidget {
  final VoidCallback onOrientationChange;

  const SettingsCameraUser({Key? key, required this.onOrientationChange}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(child: Text('Click orientation'), onPressed: onOrientationChange,),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use `setState` function to change the `state`:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        home: DefaultTabController(
          length: 4,
          child: Scaffold(
            appBar: isPortrait
                ? PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(120),
              child: AppBarService(),
            )
                : null,
            bottomNavigationBar: isPortrait ?  menu() : null,
            body: TabBarView(
              //controller: tabControllerGlobally,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              children: [
                MainPage(),
                HistoryPage(),
                DataBaseUser(),
//here my stream persist
                SettingsCameraUser(onOrientationChange: () => setState(() {
                  isPortrait = !isPortrait;
                })),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
```